Catching a raiserror from trigger with EF
I'm using .NET 6 with EF. I have a table with an insert trigger, in which I have a
raiserror (@errmsg, -1, -1)

From the .NET project, I need to catch this @errmsg after calling SaveChanges(), but I can't. All I get is

The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

I need that personalized message from @errmsg to know what's wrong.
How can I get it?
I cannot touch the SQL code.
I have tried
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    var sqlException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;

    if (sqlException != null)
    {
        int errorNumber = sqlException.Number;
        string errorMessage = sqlException.Message;
    }
}


Examine the Errors collection of the SqlException.
